# SqlPlus, tablespace parameter, and escaping the dot character

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have a Sqlplus script that I need to execute as part of a process chain, and its purpose is to get rid of two user-defined objects:

### myscript.sql

```
def tablespaceName=&1

drop type &tablespaceName.my_user_tab;
commit;
drop type &tablespaceName\.my_user_type;
commit;
/
```

Execution: Sqlplus myDbUser/myDbPassword@myDbSID @myscript.sql TESTTABLESPACE

The Sqlplus engine is somehow losing the dot character that separates the tablespace from the object name:

```
old   1: drop type &tablespaceName.my_user_tab
new   1: drop type TESTTABLESPACEmy_user_tab
drop type TESTTABLESPACEmy_user_tab
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04043: object TESTTABLESPACEMY_USER_TAB does not exist
```

How do I get Sqlplus to honor the dot and stop removing it from the script?

Comment: "tablespacename" in this context seems a very misleading name for the parameter - did you mean "schema_name" instead? I assume you are referring to the schema that owns those two particular objects.

Comment: You are confusing a "tablespace" with a "schema" - those are two *completely* different things.

Comment: Yep. I confused tablespace and schema. Now to the main point: how do I get the dot separator to stop disappearing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First of all, you don't need commit/rollback for DDLs.

And to escape the dots. Just use double dots.

```
drop type &tablespaceName..my_user_tab;
```

From [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref452)

> If you wish to append characters immediately after a substitution
>   variable, use a period to separate the variable from the character.

Comment: Source for the double dots notation?